# React and Rails app - coffee script (or bootstrap) not showing on server

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, coffeescript

I'm trying to create a simple posts app using Ruby on Rails and React. 
This is my first time creating a React app and using coffee-script so i've been online resources.

I'm at the point where I am creating a table for my posts and a table for posts.new to create a new post.

I am not getting any errors when running my server, but the everything i've written in my coffee.script is not showing up on my browser. The only thing showing is my Header 1 tag.

In my JS console I am getting errors like this:
Uncaught Error: Bootstrap tooltips require Tether

Here is my code for index.html.erb

````
```<h1>Posts#index Route navigates here</h1>
<%= react_component 'Posts', {data: @posts} %>
```
````

Here is my code for posts.js.coffee

````
```@Posts = React.createClass
     getInitialState: ->
       posts: @props.data
     getDefaultProps: ->
       posts: []
     addPost: (post) ->
       posts = @state.posts.slice()
       posts.push post
       @setState posts: posts 
     render: ->
        React.DOM.div
           className: 'posts'
           React.DOM.h1
              className: 'title'
               'Posts'
           React.createElement PostForm, handleNewPost: @addPost
           React.DOM.table
              classname: 'table table-bordered'
              React.DOM.thead null
                React.DOM.th null, 'Description'
              React.DOM.tbody null,
                 for post in @state.posts
                   React.createdElement Post, key: post.id, post: post
```
````

Here is my code for post.js.coffee:

````
```@Post = React.createClass
    render: ->
      React.DOM.tr null,
        React.DOM.td null, @props.post.description
```
````

my goal is to make a react app similar to instagram where you just post photos..i wanted to keep it simple by just adding a description for now and migrating photo_url value later. Please let me know if theres any reason my bootstrap and coffee script isnt showing! thank you!

Comment: is there any error on your browser console?

Comment: yes! i just edited the post with that error

Comment: It says i need to tether bootstrap, so I was going to add the link/script tag to my application.html.erb but I'm not sure what format to use in rails...

Comment: OK i reallllllly over-thought that like usual. Just added the script tags and it worked ..ah!

Answer (score 0):

added these 2 script tags for bootstrap in my application.html.erb head tag

````
```
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/tether@1.2.4/dist/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/bootstrap@4.0.0-
alpha.5/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```
````